# How to block Logitech unifying dongles

Tags: windows, wifi

We need to block Logitech Unifying dongles now that it's public knowledge you can both [sniff\decrypt](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-13052) keystrokes, and also [inject keystrokes](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-13053).

Is there an easy way to block these common dongles with GPO or InTune?

All I have so far is a PowerShell script to disable devices but this would have to be run after the device is plugged in, which is reactive and not preventative.

```
# Disable Unifying receivers
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Logitech*" -Class 'Mouse' | Disable-PnpDevice -confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hardware ID for Unifying Receiver I am seeing is `USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B`. This can be used as "Hardware ID" and device GUID. They both appear to refer to the same string.

**Following the [Microsoft guidance on GPO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731387(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)**

We can block devices by Hardware Ids.

Under `Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > System > Device Installation` the policy to blacklist is `Prevent installation of devices that match these device IDs`

**Following the [Microsoft guidance on InTune](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/administrative-templates-restrict-usb)**

We can block devices by class GUID of the device classes.

Under `Templates > Administrative Templates` the policy to blacklist is
`Prevent installation of devices that match any of these device IDs`

**// TODO:** I need to update this policy to include all affected devices listed on [MouseJack](http://www.bastille.net/research/vulnerabilities/mousejack/affected-devices). If I don't update this answer with all the hardware IDs, please feel free to add ones for me in either a comment or an edit.